# Foreach using list inside the lambda syntax to perform multiple where clause

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I want to perform a multiple where clause using foreach statement inside lambda list expression. It is possible to do that? Please help me. Thanks. Here's my code:

```
//The cat values are "Toys,Accessories,Shirts"
var listCategories = cat.Split(',').ToList();

var GetProd = db.vwProducts.Where(x => foreach(var category in listCategories) { x.CategoryName.ToLower().Contains(category) && } x.Status == 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my question. You do not use the foreach to loop through list.I use the List statement to loop over the query. Here's my code.

```
//cat values "Toy,Shirt,Accessories"
List<string> categories = cat.Split(',').ToList();

var GetProd = db.vwProducts.Where(x => categories.Contains(x.CategoryName) && x.Status == 1).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```